# Can the word "prairie" be derived from the arabic word "barary"

Tags: english, etymology, arabic

I've found a great similarity between the two words and their meanings.
"Barary" براري in Arabic is the plural form of "Barr-īyah" بَرِّيَّة, from the word "Barr" meaning land, with the nisbah suffix -īyah, which means pertaining to land, and its plural form was used a lot in Classical Arabic meaning vast lands -very close to the meaning in English.-

I've searched the online etymology dictionary for prairie and this is what I found:

> "tract of level or undulating grassland in North America, by 1773, from French prairie "meadow, grassland," from Old French praerie "meadow, pastureland" (12c.), from Vulgar Latin *prataria, from Latin pratum "meadow," originally "a hollow." The word existed in Middle English as prayere, but was lost and reborrowed to describe the American plains. Prairie dog is attested from 1774; prairie schooner "immigrant's wagon" is from 1841. Illinois has been the Prairie State since at least 1861. In Latin, Neptunia prata was poetic for "the sea."

But I wonder, isn't what I mention worth thinking?

Comment: No. You need more than one word; you need hundreds of such words, all with the same /bar/ --> /pr/ change, and no contradictions (like /bar/ --> /bar/, or /bar/ --> [something else altogether]). Without trying hard, it's easy to find 3 or 4 pairs of words in any pair of languages that mean something similar and sound something similar. But to establish a "derived from" relation, you need ***lots*** more evidence.

Comment: No. The first recorded use of English 'prairie' is the 16 century (OED), clearly a French borrowing 'prairie,' the latter going back to Old French 'praierie' (12th century), clearly going back to Latin pratum, of disputed etymology. Why - and most importantly, HOW (time-wise)- could ancient Romans have borrowed (roughly 7th century BC - 5th AD) this word from the Arabs (6th century AD - Classical Arabic)?

Comment: Of course, “prairie” does not come from barriyya; it has a clear-cut French/Latin etymology. On the other hand, I would like to remind our friend Alex B. that there are a reasonable number of Semitic loanwords in Greek and in Latin, many of which have Arabic cognates, that Ancient North Arabian (the ancestor of classical Arabic) is attested in inscriptions going back at least to the 4th century BC, and that the Romans did have a maritime and military presence in the Red Sea. So your chronological and geographical objections do not real hold water.

Comment: But I repeat: there is no reason to think that “prairie” comes from Arabic.

Comment: @fdb, I was unaware of Ancient North Arabian. Thanks for the friendly reminder!

Comment: Yusuf, languages abound in happy coincidences like this and they are worth investigating if you're interested in such things. This time it didn't lead anywhere other than a pair of words that might be easier for learners of each other's language to remember. It's exceedingly common in single syllable words but also very common in two syllable words. We can see they're not related because the sense drifts as we go backward in time to the Latin. You might find it interesting to see if you can trace the Arabic back any further but it doesn't look as if it used to mean "hollow".

Comment: @fdb, 1. I think there's a huge difference between Semitic loanwords in Latin (through Greek), with Arabic cognates, and English words "derived from Arabic (via Latin)" (whatever it means). I'm afraid your first point is irrelevant. 2. Could you cite some references saying Ancient North Arabian was the ancestor of classical Arabic?

Comment: 'English words "derived from Arabic (via Latin)" (whatever it means).....' Did I say that?

Comment: Ancient North Arabian belongs to same sub-group within Semitic as classical Arabic (called by some “Central Semitic”). A good overview is given by Michael Macdonald, "Reflections on the linguistic map of pre-Islamic Arabia" Arabian Archaeology and Epigraphy 11(1), 2000, 28–79.

Comment: The Arabs are mentioned in Babylonian texts from a very early time, and later by the Greek historians from Herodotus on. It is great delusion to think that the Arabs came out of nowhere in the 7th century AD. By the way, the English word “camel” < Latin < Greek is very likely to have originated in Arabic, then borrowed into other Semitic languages (Hebrew, Aramaic etc.) and into Greek. The currently favoured view is that camels were first domesticated in the Arabian paeninsula early in the early first millennium BC.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. 1. From what I can see in Macdonald 2000 - and what I already suspected from other sources - Ancient North Arabian and Old Arabic belong to the same sub-group. However, the ancestor of classical Arabic was Old Arabic, not ANA. 2. What evidence do you have of Arabic origin for Greek κάμηλος? What makes you think it originated from Arabic (Old Arabic presumably?) and not, let's say, Hebrew or Aramaic? Note that I'm *not* disputing its Semitic origin.

Comment: I suggested this as a hypothesis, not as a fact. Two things speak in its favour: First, the archaeological evidence seems to suggest that the one-humped camel was first domesticated in Arabia. Second, although widespread in Semitic, the word gammalu does not occur in Akkadian until the Neo-Assyrian period and is held by the Assyriologists to be a loanword. If it were proto-Semitic one would expect it to occur already in the rich corpus of Old Babylonian.

Answer (score 4):

The information in prairie is vast grassland as it is found in USA. I doubt that such vast grasslands existed in Arabian countries. You should check your Arabian word  whether it contains the information grass.
Vast land is not enough, the Sahara is a vast land too, but no one would take such a word as a name for grassland.

It is highly improbable that settlers in the New World looked into the Arabian language  to get a new word for the vast grassland they found in Lousiana, especiallly as the French word la praerie for meadow 
was around.

I've just looked up Arabic barari and the translation is praerie, for me that looks more like a borrowing  from the Vulgar Latin *prataria or a coinage from this form. You shoud check the etymology of barari and how old this word is. Simple affirmations about word histories are useless. And normally short words from one language don't become longer in the other language.

Comment: It does make more sense that the borrowing went the other way!

Comment: While I agree completely with your conclusion, your first paragraph is not relevant to the argument. There are many examples of loanwords that mean something rather different in the target language from their meaning in the original language. I can certainly imagine a word meaning _land_ being borrowed into another language meaning a particular type of terrain; and if the historical circumstances of the loan were appropriate, meaning a kind of terrain which was not even familiar to the speakers of the original language.

Answer (score -3):

The resemblance between "Barary" and " Prairie" is striking and there is no wrong in European languages borrowing words from Arabic. It happened in so many other words, also in English like "admiral", "alchemy", "algebra", " cotton",...etc.
But in the case of the word "prairie", I think we should dig deeper since there is a word from Latin origin- "partum" -which means meadows, that may have been reformed and coined centuries later and became the current "prairie" we know now.

Comment: I don't find it particularly striking.